# For cleaning rotors and pads and general brake parts, will any of these work as a cleaning agent: engine degreaser, carb cleaner, acetone?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-cleaner

I need to clean off some grease from the cloating on my new rotors as well as some grease on my pads. 
Aside from using brakeleen, which of the three: engine degreaser, carb cleaner, acetone would work as effectively or nearly as effective as brakeleen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "cloating" is, but nothing works as good as CRC brake cleaner.

However, given that it is banned in several states, I would start with dry paper towels to remove as much as possible, and then wipe with a clean rag wetted with gasoline.  Acetone might work, but probably not as well as gasoline.  Xylene would work fine as well, but again is fairly expensive.

A few hard stops should "burn away" any residue.  Unless there is a serious amount of grease...  What kind of grease is it, and is it just a little slop, or is it coming out of a split CV boot or something?

Dry rags and/or paper towels is where I would start in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Carb cleaner is slightly less volatile than brake cleaner but essentially the same ingredients.  Engine Degreaser in my experience leaves some slight residue as does acetone.

I would use Carb Cleaner in preference to the other two.